# Emiting VueJS event from a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a simple subscription model in my `Vuejs` application where I'm having few difficulties in maintaining the local storage. I created a class which is responsible for storage of token/key which is required in the application.

```
export default class session {

    constructor(STORAGE, INACTIVITY_SESSION) {
        this.STORAGE = STORAGE;
        this.INACTIVITY_SESSION = INACTIVITY_SESSION;
        this.key = 'session-key';
    }

    start() {
        //
    }

    setAll(all) {

    }

    getAll() {

    }

    renew(sessionId){

    }


    destroy(){
        //Some code for removal of keys.
        eventBus.$emit('destroyed');

    }

    resetTimer() {

    }
}
```

I want that whenever destroy function is called it should call an event, and this event can be captured in my application and perform action as desired. But somehow the event is emitting. I'm having import event file:

```
import {eventBus} from './_events.js';
```

and my `_event.js` file has:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

/**
 * Event bag to be used globally
 */

export const eventBus = new Vue();
```

This event bag is working inside any `.vue` file or `vue-templates` but not working in this session class. Moreover I'm importing class in vue application as:

```
import session from 'NitsModels/_session';

window.Vue = require('vue');

const sessions = new session(process.env.MIX_STORAGE_PERSIST, process.env.MIX_INACTIVITY_SESSION);
sessions.start();

//Some code for routing, vuex-store and definition of rendering component....

const layoutTwo = new Vue({
    el: '#layout-three',
    router: router,
    store,
    render:h=>h(adminLayout)
});
```

And I'm listening to this event inside my template component:

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 100%;">
        <div v-if="logged" style="height: 100%;">
            <layout-three></layout-three>
        </div>
        <div v-else style="height: 100%;">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {eventBus} from 'NitsModels/_events.js';

    export default {
        name: "admin",
        data() {
            return {
                logged: false,
            }
        },
        created() {
            eventBus.$on('destroyed', () => {
                this.$router.push({path: '/'});
                this.logged = false
            });
        },
        watch: {
            '$route' (to, from) {
                // react to route changes...
                if(to.meta.requiresAuth && !from.meta.requiresAuth)
                    this.logged = true
                if(!to.meta.requiresAuth && from.meta.requiresAuth)
                    this.logged = false
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the `destroy()` is actually called?

Comment: Yes, I'm deleting some keys from the `destory()` function and it is getting deleted.

Comment: Where are you listening to the event?

Comment: @phaberest I'm listening to this in my template. I've `vue-devtool` and I can see no events are being fired.